# DVD reader not working in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dvd

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 last December. It used to read DVDs and CDs but after many updates installed and using it excessively it only reads CDs and not DVDs! What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Also, when I wanted to install Windows 7 on my system, I inserted the Windows 7 DVD, it didn't boot from the DVD to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to clean lens of your DVD drive or buy a new one. If system cant boot from it then its a hardware issue and Ubuntu has nothing to do with it.